# Template does not exist at / error exception at- loader.py line 43

Tags: python, django, python-2.7, django-templates

I am trying to create a home page for my django project. I keep getting this error:

```
TemplateDoesNotExist at /
home.html
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://xtradev.local/
Django Version: 1.9
Exception Type: TemplateDoesNotExist
Exception Value:    
home.html
Exception Location: /home/epic/EPIC/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/loader.py in get_template, line 43
Python Executable:  /usr/bin/python
Python Version: 2.7.9
Python Path:    
['/home/epic/EPIC/EPIC-PROJECT/EPIC-Django/EPIC_AR',
 '/home/epic/EPIC/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/plat-x86_64-linux-gnu',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-tk',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-old',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload',
 '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/PILcompat',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gst-0.10',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gtk-2.0',
 '/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7']
Server time:    Thu, 8 Dec 2016 14:04:41 +0000
```

My settings.py looks like this:

```
TEMPLATES = [
{
    'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
    'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')],
    'APP_DIRS': True,
    'OPTIONS': {
        'context_processors': [
            'django.template.context_processors.debug',
            'django.template.context_processors.request',
            'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
            'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
        ],
    },
},
```

]

My templates folder is located in my project folder and contains a home.html

This is the code from loader.py (but I don't have my head around what it's doing / requesting exactly):

```
def get_template(template_name, dirs=_dirs_undefined, using=None):
"""
Loads and returns a template for the given name.

Raises TemplateDoesNotExist if no such template exists.
"""
chain = []
engines = _engine_list(using)
for engine in engines:
    try:
        # This is required for deprecating the dirs argument. Simply
        # return engine.get_template(template_name) in Django 1.10.
        if isinstance(engine, DjangoTemplates):
            return engine.get_template(template_name, dirs)
        elif dirs is not _dirs_undefined:
            warnings.warn(
                "Skipping template backend %s because its get_template "
                "method doesn't support the dirs argument." % engine.name,
                stacklevel=2)
        else:
            return engine.get_template(template_name)
    except TemplateDoesNotExist as e:
        chain.append(e)

raise TemplateDoesNotExist(template_name, chain=chain)
```

Everything appears to be right, I'm not sure what I'm overlooking. Any ideas?

UPDATE: 
VIEWS.PY

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User, Group
from django.shortcuts import render, HttpResponse
from rest_framework import filters
from rest_framework import viewsets

from serializers import UserSerializer, GroupSerializer

def home(request):
    return render(request, ('home.html'))

class UserViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = User.objects.all()
    serializer_class = UserSerializer
```

URLS.PY

```
admin.site.site_header = 'EPIC.AR Administration'

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', 'EPIC_AR.views.home', name='Home'),
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'^api/1.0/', include(router.urls)),
    url(r'^api-auth/', include('rest_framework.urls', namespace='rest_framework')),

]


Template-loader postmortem

Django tried loading these templates, in this order:

Using engine django:
django.template.loaders.filesystem.Loader: /home/epic/EPIC/EPIC-PROJECT/EPIC-Django/EPIC_AR/templates/home.html (Source does not exist)
django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader: /home/epic/EPIC/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/suit/templates/home.html (Source does not exist)
django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader: /home/epic/EPIC/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/templates/home.html (Source does not exist)
django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader: /home/epic/EPIC/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/templates/home.html (Source does not exist)
django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader: /home/epic/EPIC/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/rest_framework/templates/home.html (Source does not exist)
django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader: /home/epic/EPIC/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/crispy_forms/templates/home.html (Source does not exist)
django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader: /home/epic/EPIC/EPIC-PROJECT/EPIC-Django/EPIC_AR/home/templates/home.html (Source does not exist)
```

[image]

Comment: this error is all over your project, or just in one app? If only one app, show the views of this apps

Comment: And one more question, where is `home.html` exists?

Comment: I guess my project - i only have one template I'm trying to get working as a home page. I don't have any others. I've tried putting it in an app and that doesn't work either. home.html exists in the main project folder at the app level - not IN an app and not in the same folder as the settings.py (although it was at that level before) I moved it to try something different.

Comment: so, show your `view.py` and `urls.py`

Comment: Usually the the error page tells you the locations that Django tried to load the template. If so, then please include that in your question.

Comment: the view will render an HttpResponse - so I think those are ok - it just doesn't seem to be finding ANY templates

Comment: where is your `home.html` exist? is it in root of the `templates` folder? And does your `templates` folder is in the root of the project?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It was a combination of the things suggested - just a matter of getting the right sequence of things I guess.

I added the directory the home.html was located in:(in views.py)

```
def home(request):
return render(request, 'epicar/home.html')
```

Then I moved the templates folder BACK into the main project directory:

[image]

```
sudo service apache2 restart
```

and wala!

[image]

no errors. :)

Comment: It also depends on the version of Django you are using. For version  3. >, you may not need to include 'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')], because Django has a way of auto-handling templates definition in your project. The ideal thing to do is to ensure that all your app directory have templates/appname in the appname directory before returning your rendered templates .

Answer (score 2):

Usually when I get this error I've forgotten to add the app the the `INSTALLED_APPS` setting.

The default loader looks in `TEMPLATES['DIRS']` and then a templates folder in the root of each app specified in `INSTALLED_APPS`

Comment: all of the apps are installed in the settings.py. My templates folder is located in the main project folder. I had it in the main one and then I moved it up a level to see if that would help. So it's currently at the same level as all of the apps within the project.

Answer (score 1):

According to your view and settings file, `home.html` have to be in `templates` folder.

So change the path of the `home.html` in the view, from:

```
def home(request):
    return render(request, ('home.html'))
```

to

```
def home(request):
    return render(request, ('pathtoapp/home.html'))
```

or move `home.html` in the root of `templates`

Comment: Nope. Just tried it. Same error except now it lists the file path:

TemplateDoesNotExist at /
EPIC_AR/templates/epicar/home.html
Request Method: GET
Request URL: http://xtradev.local/
Django Version: 1.9
Exception Type: TemplateDoesNotExist
Exception Value: 
/EPIC-Django/EPIC_AR/templates/epicar/home.html
Exception Location: /home/epic/EPIC/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/loader.py in get_template, line 43

Comment: It is hard to answer your question, cause i don't see full  structure of your project with it folder names

Answer (score 0):

write your 'templates' name correct in setting.py insatalledApp , DIRS['templates'] and restart server